# Add object of type T to object of type List<T>

Tags: c#

I'm busy building my own property grid.  One of the issues that I'm struggling with currently is dealing with collections.  Specifically adding a new item to a collection.

I have an object called CollectionDataSource that is a List containing objects of type T.

I'm getting the type of T and creating a new T object as follows:

```
var type = CollectionDataSource.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();
var newItem = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Now I need to add newItem to CollectionDataSource.  The problem is CollectionDataSource is of type object.  I've tried casting to IEnumerable and ICollection but those interfaces cannot add a new item.

How can I add newItem to CollectionDataSource?

***UPDATE***

See my answer below.  All I had to do was cast the collection to IList.  That did the trick for me

Comment: You can cast to an IEnumerable then cast to a List or cast straight to a List?

Comment: How to I cast to a list if I don't know upfront the Type of the list?

Comment: How can you even be sure that the type of `CollectionDataSource` _supports_ the operation of adding elements?

Comment: @Sweeper there is no guarrantee but it SHOULD be that way.  If not then obviously an error will be thrown which is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the answer is simple.  All that I had to do was cast CollectionDataSource to (IList).  Problem solved

```
    var type = CollectionDataSource.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();
    var newItem = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    var a = (IList)CollectionDataSource;
    a.Add(newItem);
```

Comment: What was the problem then? Explicit interface implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Why not cast it to a List in the first place?

```
var myObject = something as List<object>;

if (myObject != null)
{
  // successfully cast
}
else
{
  // cast failed
}
```

Or you if you know the type:

```
public static Object TryConvertTo<T>(string input)
{
    Object result = null;
    try
    {
        result = Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: var c = CollectionDataSource as List<object> gives me a null variable

Comment: CollectionDataSource and newItem are of the same type.  Thus newItem can be addedto CollectionDataSource, but the problem is the type is not known beforehand.  I need to determine this during runtime somehow and cast CollectionDataSource  which is an object to List<T> where T is defined during runtime

Answer (score 0):

```
T toAdd = Convert.ChangeType((IItemsSource)Activator.CreateInstance(type), typeof(T));
```

Then create a simple Add method:

```
public void Add<T>(T toAdd) where T: class { _list.Add(toAdd); }
```